# Multiple Integration of a function defined for a list of arguments

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to calculate, by *Mathematica*, the following integral of a function defined with a list of arguments.

$$\int_1^2\int_1^2\int_1^2 (x+y+z)^4 \, dx\, dy \, dz$$

as follows:

```
f[{x_, y_, z_}] := (x + y + z)^4

NIntegrate[f[x, y, z], {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}, {z, 1, 2}]
```

but it doesn't calculate the integral. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replace `f[x,y,z]` by `f[{x,y,z}]` in the integral? Alternatively, you can change the definition of `f` to `f[x_,y_,z_]:=(x+y+z)^4` so without `{` and `}`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mathematica SE. The community is happy to help you, but we may not want to keep this question open for long after you solved your problem. Therefore, your question may [closed](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it is technically [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD). That is because it arises from a simple syntax mistake easily found in the documentation and it's unlikely to help any future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning up policy. This and your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Comment: Perhaps, `Integrate[(x + y + z)^4, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}, {z, 1, 2}]`, which yields `2203/5`, meets your needs.

Answer (score 3):

## The problem

You have defined your function with a particular [pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html) `{x_, y_, z_}`

```
ClearAll[f];
f[{x_, y_, z_}] := (x + y + z)^4
```

If you try to evaluate your function `f` with a pattern that doesn't match the pattern in your definition, then it will return without evaluation.

```
f[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> f[1, 2, 3]
> ```

If you use an argument that matches the [pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html) as defined it will evaluate

```
f[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> 1296
> ```

## Solution

As pointed out by @user293787, just define the pattern the same way you intend to use it.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_, y_, z_] := (x + y + z)^4

NIntegrate[
 f[x, y, z]
 , {x, 1, 2}
 , {y, 1, 2}
 , {z, 1, 2}
 ]
```

> 440.6